# Odoo 13: Contacts: Filter/Search - Get all individuals of companies with condition (category_id == 'Services')

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

Module Contacts: How to get all individuals of companies with a certain condition (e.g. category_id == 'Services'). Obviously condition may vary. I would like to use it in filter or search functions.

Comment: `self.env['res.partner'].search([('category_id', '=', 'Services')]).child_ids` will return all contacts of all partners with `Services` tag

Answer (score 0):

```
all_companies_with_service = self.env['res.partner'].search([('category_id', '=', 'services')]).ids

patners = self.env['res.partner'].search(['&',('company_id', 'in', all_companies_with_service), ('is_company', '=', False)])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your command returns all contacts with category_id equals to 'Services'. I would like to get all individuals of companies that category_id == 'Services'. That means all those individuals do not have to equal to 'Services'.

Comment: Hello, I understand now, so you want a list of employees where company.category_id == 'service' :      `all_companies_with_service = self.env['res.partner'].search([('category_id', '=', 'services')]).ids  employees = self.env['hr.employee'].search([('company_id', 'in', all_companies_with_service)]) `

Comment: now syntax might now be correct but I believe that's roughly the domain you're operator yous should be looking into  `in`

Comment: I do not want employees. I want individuals ('res.parnter') but only those who are not companies. Moreover, I would like to have it in Search or Filter functions. Thanks!

Comment: Okay so  `res.partners` that have `is_company` as `False`, and have a `company_id` where that `company_id` is a `res.partner' that have a field where `category_id` is `Service` ?

Comment: You should use `Services` instead